# Trying install XCODE on m MAC

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to install xcode on my mac .I tried two options.

1). using command line tools.

I typed xcode-select --install but it gives me below error.

xcode-select: Error: no command option given.

xcode-select: Report or change the path to the active
              Xcode installation for this machine.

Usage: xcode-select --print-path
           Prints the path of the active Xcode folder
   or: xcode-select --switch 
           Sets the path for the active Xcode folder
   or: xcode-select --version
           Prints the version of xcode-select

2). After that i tried to install it from App store but even there it is giving me error as

Xcode can’t be installed on “Machintosh HD” because OS X version 10.9.4 or later is required.

BTW i am trying to install xcode version 6.1.

Could any one help me why i am not able to install xcode on my MAC.

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 6):

I think the second error message told you all you need to know. You need to be running OS X 10.9.4 or later.